# How to export Spearman correlations

Tags: stata

I am trying to export the Spearman correlation matrix into an `rtf` or Excel file using `estpost` and the *community-contributed* command `esttab`.

However, I am getting the following error:

```
invalid subcommand
r(198);
```

Below is my code:

```
estpost spearman varlists, matrix stats(rho p) star(.05)
estimates store cl

esttab * using corrtable.rtf, b(%6.3f) label alignment(l) unstack not noobs compress replace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spearman` command does not work with `estpost`, which is why Stata complains.

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear

spearman price mpg weight
matrix A = r(Rho)

esttab matrix(A, fmt(%5.2f)) using corrtable.rtf

---------------------------------------------------
                        A                          
                    price          mpg       weight
---------------------------------------------------
price                1.00        -0.54         0.49
mpg                 -0.54         1.00        -0.86
weight               0.49        -0.86         1.00
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest update, `asdocx` users can now export output from the `spearman` command. This update allows users to export Spearman’s correlation tables directly to various formats such as Excel, Word, HTML, or LaTeX. Here is one example; explore more [here](https://asdocx.com/export-spearman-correlation-to-word-excel-latex-from-stata/).

```
    * Load example data
webuse states2

* export the table to MS Excel
asdocx spearman mrgrate divorce_rate medage, save(Spearman.xlsx) star(.05) replace
```

[image]

In the spirit of transparency, I’d like to inform you that `asdocx` is paid software, available for purchase at USD 9.99. I am the developer of this software.